# Should the output of a USB-UART module linked to a bluetooth module the same than just the USB-UART module just wired?

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I have a device controled by a UART protocol just conected to my PC.

I wanted to make it wireless, so I tried to create this conexion scheme

> PC -> USB-UART -> Bluetooth module -> Bluetooth module -> my device

When I connect the USB-UART just to my device it works perfectly, by if a use the bluetooth module it doesn't work.

I have also try to use configuration PC1 -> USB-UART -> Bluetooth module -> Bluetooth module -> UART-USB -> PC2 in order to test if the comunication is allright and I have been able to talk between the PCs in both directions.

What could be the problem? Could the bluetooth module changing my format data?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: And, your programming question is......

Comment: it was more a electronic-programing question. 
It was just if that bluetooth module could modify the data or the data format.